# SQL Server 2008 select constraints order by primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, constraints

I have the following SQL statement to retrieve drop constraint statements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'ALTER TABLE '+TABLE_NAME+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'DropConstraintStatement'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'USER';
```

The result of this query is:

1. ALTER TABLE UNITS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TASK_ID
2. ALTER TABLE UNITS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_USER
3. ALTER TABLE UNITS DROP CONSTRAINT UQ_USER_NAME_VERSION

I want to execute these statements within a Java application, hence I need these statements ordered such that the drop primary key constraint is at the last position like:

1. ALTER TABLE UNITS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TASK_ID
2. ALTER TABLE UNITS DROP CONSTRAINT UQ_USER_NAME_VERSION
3. ALTER TABLE UNITS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_USER

Is there any nice possibility to do this with native SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE` does not hold the necessary information to distinguish between PK and other constraints. If you are sure your PK names start with PK
you could try adding `ORDER BY` like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

However, I would suggest switching to SQL Server system views for more precise data. `sys.key_constraints` holds info about primary keys and unique constraints, and `sys.foreign_keys` about foreign keys.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TABLE_NAME
        , name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME, Type
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('YourTable')

    UNION

    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TABLE_NAME
        , name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME, Type
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('YourTable')
)
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '+TABLE_NAME+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'DropConstraintStatement'
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Type = 'PK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! It works fine for me. I just added union check constraints too, in case that such one exists for that table.